# What is the difference between the default groups on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, permissions

Two questions:

1. What's the difference between the groups "wheel", "staff", and "admin"? What do they do?
2. specific use case: I'm trying to setup a local CVS repository as stated in [the Apple webpage](http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/cvsoverview.html) so I can download a remote source tree... and I have to get myself permission to use a new directory `/usr/local/cvsrep`. It gets created by default as owned by "root" under group "wheel"... but I don't have membership in "wheel", I do have membership in "admin" and "staff" and am just wondering if I should `chgrp` the directory to admin or staff instead of wheel.

Comment: Are you just trying to download the source of some project that only you are going to hack on?  You can just download it to a folder that you have permissions on already.

Comment: Oh. you're correct... well, then the 2nd part of the Q is moot for my own purposes. But I'd still like to know about my first question.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Regular OS X users are put into the **staff** group.

Admin users are put in the **staff** and **admin** groups. The **admin** group can do some things that other users cannot do. e.g. Write to the `/Applications` folder.  If you want to put an OS X user into the **admin** group you should do this by designating him as an admin via *System Preferences->Users & Groups*.

root is the only member of the **wheel** group, and should remain the only member.  If you have to do something that requires wheel, you should use the command `sudo`.

Comment: "wheel" is a pretty bad name for that

Comment: do you know a reference for this info? I'd like to read more about it. thanks!

Comment: I know it is bad but I have a Mac not connected to Internet and want to sudo commands without typing password. Do I have to make an entry in `sudoers` with `myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: @justin-zhang I agree with you. The name "wheel" is inherited by macOS from its BSD UNIX heritage. In turn, BSD gets this from TENEX. The name is originally derived from 1960s/1970s slang "big wheel" for a person with great powers - as in the big wheel of a tricycle or a penny-farthing bicycle. Yes, very antiquated. I don't think that the slang is current any more, but the name persists. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_(computing)

Comment: It is misleading to say that a user is put into a group. Rather a group is added to a user. A user may have multiple groups.