# Why can't I delete this file?

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I run `brew doctor`, I get this warning:

```
Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libusb-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
    /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
```

According to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580813/how-do-i-fix-brew-doctor-errors), I want to delete these files.

But when I remove the second one with `rm`, it seems to be recreated automatically:

```
$ rm /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel for /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib? 
$ ls /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
```

I totally don't understand what's going on. Why can't I delete this file?

Comment: So when it asked you to override, what did you answer?

Comment: It looks like they just pressed return. I think `rm` defaults to `n` when you don't give it a valid reply (or at least when you enter nothing).

Comment: @Tetsu You mean `brew doctor`, right?

Comment: @BlacklightShining Ya, as you assume, I just pressed return. I deleted by answering `y`. Thanks!

Comment: @BlacklightShining And yes, I meant `brew doctor`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rm` is telling you that you don't have write access to the file you told it to delete, and is asking for confirmation. Type <kbd>y</kbd> and then press <kbd>return</kbd> when it asks you if you want to override. If you type <kbd>n</kbd> or nothing at all, it won't delete the file.

---

Technical(ish) details:

`rwxr-xr-x root/wheel` is a representation of the permissions and ownership of the file.

The first part tells you the permissions of the file; the second that the file is owned by the user [`root`](https://superuser.com/tags/root/info) and the group [`wheel`](https://superuser.com/questions/20420/what-is-the-difference-between-the-default-groups-on-mac-os-x).

See [`man chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) for more information on file ownership, and [`man chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) for more information on file permissions. Wikipedia might have easier-to-understand information on [`chown`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chown) and [`chmod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/chmod).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use sudo...

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/libusbpp-0.1.4.4.4.dylib
```

that should do it

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is accurate for the contents of `/usr/local/`. MacOS has something called System Integrity Protection, which restricts the actions of superuser. Attempts to alter the contents of `/usr/bin` and other folders may be rejected with *Operation not permitted*. This is described in [which folders are affected by System Integrity Protection](https://superuser.com/a/1051216/1125800).

Comment: THANK YOU! Among the many answers I've read about this issue, this is the first one I've seen that mentions MacOS's System Integrity Protection, which indeed was what was causing my problem.