# custom facetime/message ringtones in OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, permissions, facetime

I had previously made custom ringtones as .m4r files and copied them into ..tonelibrary.framework/..../ringtones, by matching my custom tones' name to an existing tone (i.e. Harp.m4r) then simply dropping the .m4r into the ringtone folder to replacing the original.

Since updating to Sierra the ringtones have all been reset to the default files and every time I try and drop an .m4r in I see the grey crossed out circle icon.
When I try to change permission to read & write in get info I am greeted with the dialogue box "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission"

How do I get the permission back? I want my custom ringtones again!
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Since El Capitan, many system locations as discussed in [Which folders are affected by System Integrity Protection?](https://superuser.com/questions/1049689/which-folders-are-affected-by-system-integrity-protection) are protected by System Integrity Protection. You'll need to disable this to make changes to system files.

> To disable System Integrity Protection, you can do the following:
>
> 1. Boot into the Recovery HD by restarting whilst holding ⌘R.
> 2. Open Terminal (from the Utilities menu).
> 3. Run the following command in Terminal:
>
>    ```
>    csrutil disable
>    ```
> 4. Restart.

<sup>[Package is incompatible with this version of OS X](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/package-incompatible-installer/)</sup>

SIP can be re-enabled once you've made your changes.